# Vagrant + Composer + Windows / nfs / git error

Tags: linux, windows, vagrant, composer-php, nfs

I have a following problem: when i run `composer update` inside virtual machine i got that error message:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
   - Installing friendsofsymfony/user-bundle (dev-master f54031a)
     Failed to download friendsofsymfony/user-bundle from source: Could
not delete
/var/www/agroit/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_0neozU:

[RuntimeException]
   Could not delete
/var/www/agroit/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_0neozU:
```

and of course when I do it on my computer (not in virtual machine) everything works fine.

I mount filesystem on nfs but this not working also on 'default' vagrant settings.  As I understand problem is that virtual machine dont have full/proper acces to windows filesystem. So what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know NFS won't be stable when you use it on Windows.

First of all, looking at your error, I don't know why you have your `vendor` directory under version control. Normally you should put in GIT only `composer.json` and `composer.lock` and not the `vendor` directory itself.

But let's continue on main topic - NFS is not stable on Windows and using it with Vagrant will cause many side effects and errors that are hard to detect. For example when I use it, sometimes when I run for example `composer install` some files are corrupted and it's really hard to track the problem when you know this is NFS issue.

So my recommendation is not to use NFS on Windows - I know that Vagrant will be slow without NFS but in case you want to test your app and not to solve all the time problems with NFS, you should not use it or install Linux as primary system and use Vagrant in Linux.

Comment: 1. i don't have vendors on git, that is update on older version;)
2. and yes, i gave up with this error. although I have to use NFS and Windows because that is my environment at work. So my workaround for this bug is simply install local PHP on windows and use it only for composer.  I work in this way for some time and other problems i haven't noticed